# double* android ndk crash

Tags: c++, pointers, android-ndk

I'm facing a peculiar problem with the android ndk. I'm trying to read a previously stored set of bytes in an `unsigned char* readBytes` (previous allocated and read from file). The data needs to be interpreted as double.

```
unsigned char* svDataOffset=(unsigned char*)(readBytes+byteCounter);

unsigned char* chars=(unsigned char*)(svDataOffset+2); //offset of 2 is where the data is
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"va","%x   %u   %u   %u %u",chars[0],svDataOffset,shortPointer,doublePointer,chars);//print all the addresses
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[1]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[2]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[3]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[4]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[5]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"index","%x",chars[6]);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"va","%x",chars[7]);

double* ptr=(double*)chars;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"va","%u  ",ptr);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"val"," %x",*ptr++);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"val"," %x",*ptr);
```

In the above code, I take the address of the location where the double data starts in an unsigned char and print out the data, which is the exact data I wanted. But when I try to access it as a `double*` or `long long*` the program crashes. The same set of bytes can be read as `float*` or `int*` with crashing (gives some garbage values).

Here's the error:

```
06-23 14:24:57.166: A/libc(11913): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x7cc20236 (code=1), thread 11913
```

Logact output:

```
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/va(22471): 74   2093089332   2093089332   2093089334  2093089334
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): 22
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): 56
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): 9b
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): 33
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): e
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/index(22471): e9
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/va(22471): 3f
06-23 15:26:00.771: I/va(22471): 2093089334  
06-23 15:26:00.771: A/libc(22471): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x7cc20236 (code=1), thread 22471 (e.ohr.tamilohwr)
```

Please help with the error.

Thank you.

Comment: What do your log statements print? Please add logcat output to the question.

Comment: I actually added it in the question. Here it is :06-23 14:24:57.166: A/libc(11913): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x7cc20236 (code=1), thread 11913

Comment: I mean what is the output of `__android_log_print` statements? Nothing?

Comment: here it is:` 06-23 15:25:29.901: I/va(22373): 74   2145903156   2145903156   2145903158  2145903158
`06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): 22'
`06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): 56'
`06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): 9b'
'06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): 33'
'06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): e'
'06-23 15:25:29.901: I/index(22373): e9'
'06-23 15:25:29.901: I/va(22373): 3f'
'06-23 15:25:29.901: I/va(22373): 2145903158'

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to format it properly. The actual data that was supposed to be there was printed.

Comment: logcat output added, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several possible causes.

1. First of all, casting `char*` to `double*` and then accessing it through that pointer is undefined behavior. Most of time it works, but you are warned.
2. Pointer misalignment. `double` is most likely supposed to be aligned to 8 bytes, and you read it through pointer equal to `2093089334` that is `0x7CC20236` - obviously not aligned to 8 bytes. This can be critical on ARM processors.
3. Wrong formatting mode: you are trying to print `double` with `%x` which is wrong. Use `%f`, `%g` or anything else appropriate.

To fix both (1) and (2) allocate `double*` separately, and `memcpy` appropriate part of data into it.

Comment: All the data in the  readBytes array is read from a file. This file has an arrangement of data in the form: 2bytes, 8 bytes, 2 bytes, 8bytes........This is read into the readBytes array. Then read. So, most possibly, its misalignment. How do i solve this?

Comment: It worked! I memcpied the data to a new pointer and read it. It worked perfectly. Thank you for the help. Now i atleast know the problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...This is not something defined in c right? It should've been independent of the architecture.

Comment: Since C++11 there's `[basic.align]` chapter in the standard which introduces alignment requirements. In C11 it's essentially the same, see 6.3.2.3/7.